# Example of a field extension of a cyclotomic extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have for example the cyclotomic field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$ . And I think it's possible:  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\zeta_3})$ . Then it will be possible the field extension of the cyclotomic extension:  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt{\zeta_3})$ .

How  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)$  and  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\zeta_3})$ are linearly disjoint over $\mathbb{Q}$ , I have to multiply its two respective bases to get the basis of  $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt{\zeta_3})$ .

Then:  $K=\{1,\zeta_3\}\,\,x\,\, \{1,\sqrt{\zeta_3}\}\,=\,\{1,\,\zeta_3,\,\sqrt{\zeta_3},\,\,\zeta_3\sqrt{\zeta_3}\}$

Is it correct?

Is it truly the basis  $k_1=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\zeta_3})=\{1,\sqrt{\zeta_3}\}$ , how I'm thinking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which extension do you finally consider?  $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt{\zeta_3})$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Yes

Comment: It would be "more interesting" to consider the fields obtained by adding successively $3^n$-roots of $\zeta_3$.

Comment: @nguyenquangdo True. $ \left( \dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} \right)^2=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ . What would X of:  $X^3=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ ?

Comment: You don't need to do any computation if you know about cyclotomic fields. If $p$ is an odd prime, let $\zeta_n$ denote a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity. Then $\mathbf Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbf Q$ is a cyclic extension of degree $p^{n-1}(p-1)$. In particular, for $n \ge 2, \mathbf Q(\zeta_n)/\mathbf Q(\zeta_1)$ is cyclic of degree $p^{n-1}$

Comment: @nguyenquangdo Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{\zeta_3}$. Since $a^2=\zeta_3$ we have $a^6=1$ and $a$ is a $6$-th root of unity. However, we have
$$
\Bbb Q(\zeta_6)=\Bbb Q(\zeta_3),
$$
see here: [Is $\mathbb Q(\zeta_6)=\mathbb {Q}(\zeta_3)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838578/is-mathbb-q-zeta-6-mathbb-q-zeta-3)

So the degree is indeed $2$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde :  Thank you!